# Microsoft Graph API - Microsoft Teams Create Event with gmail user as attendee

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to send an MS Teams meeting invite to a Gmail user(guest) using graph API.
I can send it to people under my organization or to another organization with an AD account.
When I add a Gmail user, a meeting is getting created but not sent an invite to a gmail user.
There are no records in the Gmail spam folder also. Any reason or I'm missing something.

One thing noticed one thing in MS Teams desktop app, when I add a Gmail user to teams, it's asking to invite that user. Is there anything I should do related to that when I'm using it from API?

Another thing I have noticed is that there is a setting in Azure portal inside authentication support account type :

Who can use this application or access this API?

- Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)

Attaching the sample code which I have tried. This is working when I add the same AD or different AD account as an attendee but not Gmail(personal account)

```
 curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{userid}}/events' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--header 'Prefer: outlook.timezone="Asia/Dubai"' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "subject": "Let'\''s Meet for Demo",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does noon work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2021-08-27T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Asia/Dubai"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2021-08-27T13:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Asia/Dubai"
  },
  "location":{
      "displayName":"John'\''s Dev Room"
  },
  "attendees": [    
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"user1@gmail.com",
        "name": "User1"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
  "isOnlineMeeting": true,
  "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to use Microsoft Graph API's onlinemeeting API to create with personal Account (Delegated permissions) its not supported. Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invitation adds an external user to the organization. When the user is invited, a user entity (of userType Guest) is created and can now be used to control access to resources. The invited user has to go through the redemption process to access any resources he has been invited to.
You can follow this link to create an invite: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Also as mentioned in [create OnlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) doc, Administrators must create an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) and grant it to a user, authorizing the app configured in the policy to create an online meeting on behalf of that user (user ID specified in the request path).
Please make sure you have added all the required policies and permissions.